# Admob recibe solicitudes pero no imprime Ad failed to load:3

Tags: android, admob

Hace tiempo hice una app y le añadí anuncios con admob, y sin problema. Recientemente con una nueva app no carga nunca anuncios, ya ha pasado una semana y sigue sin imprimir anuncios, con el error`Ad failed to load ad:3`.
La app anterior he comprobado que funciona, y he hecho una nueva version para ver que pasaba, y esta nueva version tambien es incapaz de imprimir anuncios aunque la version anterior actualmente si funciona.
¿Como es que ha ocurrido esto y como puedo solucionarlo?
Se que ese error lo que viene a decir es que es fallo de admob al cagar anuncios, pero el simple cambio de version de una misma app ha hecho que deje de funcionar y cualquier nueva tambien.

Comment: Considera agregar tu código, de otra forma es difícil saber que sucede. Revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: No hace falta código, pues el error como bien he explicado es debido a algún error de android con admob, que nada tiene que ver con mi código.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema. ¿Conseguiste solucionarlo?